# reactjs function is calling after assigning variables

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React from 'react'
    import FormatUrl from 'utils/UrlFormatter'
    import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
    import * as am4maps from "@amcharts/amcharts4/maps";
    import am4geodata_worldHigh from "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldHigh";
    import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";

    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

    class WorldMap extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                bubble:{},
                prevEvent: null,
                geodata:{}
            }
        }

        getGeography(){
          let url = FormatUrl(`/worldmap/`)
          fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            localStorage.setItem("india", res['india'])
            localStorage.setItem("us", res['us'])
            localStorage.setItem("uk", res['uk'])
          })
        }



        customComponentDidMount() {
        let chart = am4core.create("worldmap", am4maps.MapChart);
        chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldHigh;
        chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Mercator();
        chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
        chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

        this.getGeography()

        let groupData = [
            {
                "name": "India",
                "color": chart.colors.getIndex(localStorage.getItem("india")),
                "data": [
                    {
                        "title": "India",
                        "id": "IN",
                        "customData": localStorage.getItem("india")
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Usa",
                "color": chart.colors.getIndex(localStorage.getItem("us")),
                "data": [
                    {
                        "title": "Usa",
                        "id": "US",
                        "customData": localStorage.getItem("us")
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Uk",
                "color" : chart.colors.getIndex(localStorage.getItem("us")),
                "data": [
                    {
                        "title": "Uk",
                        "id": "GB",
                        "customData": localStorage.getItem("uk")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        let excludedCountries = ["AQ"];
        groupData.forEach(function(group) {
        let series = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
        series.name = group.name;
        series.useGeodata = true;
        let includedCountries = [];
        group.data.forEach(function(country){
            includedCountries.push(country.id);
            excludedCountries.push(country.id);
        });
        series.include = includedCountries;
        series.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
        series.setStateOnChildren = true;
        let seriesHoverState = series.states.create("hover");
        let mapPolygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
        mapPolygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
        mapPolygonTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.8;
        mapPolygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;
        mapPolygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{title} Has {customData} AbsM"; // enables tooltip
        series.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group.data));
        });
        let worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
        let worldSeriesName = "world";
        worldSeries.name = worldSeriesName;
        worldSeries.useGeodata = true;
        worldSeries.exclude = excludedCountries;
        worldSeries.fillOpacity = 0.8;
        worldSeries.hiddenInLegend = true;
        worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.nonScalingStroke = true;

    }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.chart) {
          this.chart.dispose();
        }
      }

        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="chart-area" id="worldmap"  style={{ width: "100%", height: '455px' }}>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default WorldMap;
```

Here i am using **amcharts** with **reactjs**.

I am displaying data whatever data coming from api.

I am not changing all data.
I am only changing the color index from api data in the map for **"us", "uk", "india"** regions

So in **customComponentDidMount**() i am calling **getGeography**() function and storing colors in localStorage as per the country.

But, the problem is this.**getGeography**() function is getting called later so my map is not getting data from localStorage.

And it is throwing error.

How to call **getGeography**() at first then to do rest of the stuffs.

Api response i am getting.

```
    {
    "us":10,
    "uk":23,
    "india":33
    }
```

Any way without using **localStorage** is also helpful.

Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are fetching data from API so this function is asynchronous. An easy solution is to pass a callback parameter in getGeography(), so it becomes:

```
getGeography(cb = null){
      let url = FormatUrl(`/worldmap/`)
      fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("india", res['india'])
        localStorage.setItem("us", res['us'])
        localStorage.setItem("uk", res['uk'])

        if (cb) {
           cb();
        }
      })
    }
```

so in your componentDidMount, you can pass your following functions into this callback:

```
 customComponentDidMount() {
    let chart = am4core.create("worldmap", am4maps.MapChart);
    chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldHigh;
    chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Mercator();
    chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
    chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

    this.getGeography(() => {
       let groupData = [
        {
            "name": "India",
            "color": chart.colors.getIndex(localStorage.getItem("india")),
            "data": [
                {
                    "title": "India",
                    "id": "IN",
                    "customData": localStorage.getItem("india")
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Usa",
            "color": chart.colors.getIndex(localStorage.getItem("us")),
            "data": [
                {
                    "title": "Usa",
                    "id": "US",
                    "customData": localStorage.getItem("us")
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Uk",
            "color" : chart.colors.getIndex(localStorage.getItem("us")),
            "data": [
                {
                    "title": "Uk",
                    "id": "GB",
                    "customData": localStorage.getItem("uk")
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    let excludedCountries = ["AQ"];
    groupData.forEach(function(group) {
    let series = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    series.name = group.name;
    series.useGeodata = true;
    let includedCountries = [];
    group.data.forEach(function(country){
        includedCountries.push(country.id);
        excludedCountries.push(country.id);
    });
    series.include = includedCountries;
    series.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
    series.setStateOnChildren = true;
    let seriesHoverState = series.states.create("hover");
    let mapPolygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
    mapPolygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
    mapPolygonTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.8;
    mapPolygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;
    mapPolygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{title} Has {customData} AbsM"; // enables tooltip
    series.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group.data));
    });
    let worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    let worldSeriesName = "world";
    worldSeries.name = worldSeriesName;
    worldSeries.useGeodata = true;
    worldSeries.exclude = excludedCountries;
    worldSeries.fillOpacity = 0.8;
    worldSeries.hiddenInLegend = true;
    worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.nonScalingStroke = true;
    })
}
```

Another option is to use async/await. So you can set

```
 async getGeography(cb = null){}
```

as async function and then call

```
await this.getGeography()
```

in componentDidMount so the code below won't run until the promise is fulfilled.